# When I include scanf() in my C code it doesn't work

Tags: c, scanf

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("You are %d years old!",age);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code I get this in the output:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\kathh\Documents\Code\C\" && gcc test.c -o test && "c:\Users\kathh\Documents\Code\C\"test
```

And when I force stop it I get this in the output:

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 6.412 seconds
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you running it from an interactive shell? Note: you should always check that `scanf` succeeds: `if(scanf("%d",&age) == 1) printf("You are %d years old!",age);`

Comment: What OS and programming environment are you using?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I'm using windows 10 and I use VS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `fflush(stdout);` immediately after each line that calls `printf`.

Comment: Or put a newline in the `printf` call.  `stdout` is line-buffered.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, although it does print "Enter your age: " it still doesn't detect input and gives me code=1 when I force stop it.

Comment: @Hextav Are you running the program from an interactive shell?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I'm not completely sure what an interactive shell is but I'm using VS code if that's the problem.

Comment: Try starting the program from a prompt, not from within VS code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your anwser, I've figured out why it's not working. It was because I needed to run the .exe file of it in a command prompt.

Comment: It sounds like calling `fflush` solved the problem of not seeing the output, and running from a shell solved the problem of not being able to give input to the program.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score -2):

Exit Code 1 indicates that the program exited unsuccessful.
If you don't even get printf to output "Enter your age" then you're somehow not running the program properly, use and IDE if you're a beginner.
Also note you should get userinput with gets() function and then convert to desired datatype.

Comment: I would imagine that a "force stop" will always cause an exit code 1.

Comment: I tried using the gets() function but I still have the same problem as with the scanf() function, where it doesn't detect input.